# How to create a single page application using react-router in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

My site is a combination of multi-page application and single-page application web application, in the multi-page jump can use the default route of nextjs, but in some pages, I want to use react-router to implement the route of single-page application. How can I achieve this? Do you have a good example?

Comment: Why do you need `react-router`, nextjs provides `useRouter()` hook to achive this.

Comment: Nextjs uses file-based routing, where you put your routes as files in the pages folder. You don't need `react-router`

Comment: What I want is to implement a single page application in nextjs, where clicking on a link just loads a different component in the current specific area, instead of reloading the whole page altogether

Comment: @Andrew.Royal maybe you just need the [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) component for that. Use anchor tags inside `Link` instead of directly using them to prevent reloading the web page and faster navigation among components. Also, page based routing is handled by Next.js out of the box. [Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction)